# Serialize enum struct that have cases with arguments

Tags: ios, serialization, enums, swift2, deserialization

I have an enum struct like that:

```
enum MyStruct {
    case CanRegister(String, String)
    case Register(String, String, String, String, String?)
    case Login(String, String)
    ...
}
```

Is it possible to ***serialize / encode and decode*** struct like that so I can easily save states to NSUserDefaults?

I know how to serialize custom structs, even enums that are of type: enum MyStruct : String{}, but can I do that with that kind of structure and how?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you want a general method here, rather than one hard-coded for your specific `enum`. I haven't worked it all the way through, but using `Mirror` is where you should start. Consider this as a hint rather than an answer...

(p.s. this is based on ideas from [this article](https://appventure.me/2015/10/24/swift-reflection-api-what-you-can-do/))

```
enum MyStruct {
    case IntVal(Int)
    case CanRegister(String, String)
    case Register(String, String, String, String, String?)
    case Login(String, String)
    // ...
}

func prettyPrint(_ any: Any) -> String {
    let m = Mirror(reflecting: any)
    var a: String
    switch m.displayStyle {
    case .some(.tuple):
        a = "Tuple"
    case .some(.enum):
        a = "Enum"
    default:
        return "\(m.displayStyle)"
    }
    a += " \(m.subjectType) = ("
    for case let (label?, value) in m.children {
        a += "\(label), \(value)"
    }

    return a + ")"
}

let ab = MyStruct.CanRegister("A", "B")
let i = MyStruct.IntVal(7)
prettyPrint(ab) // "Enum MyStruct = (CanRegister, ("A", "B"))"
prettyPrint(i)  // "Enum MyStruct = (IntVal, 7)"
```